# What is the probability of at least one of the colours not appearing in the series of throws?

Tags: probability, dice

A symmetrical 8-sided dice has three red, one yellow and four green sides. Dice is thrown three times. What is the probability of at least one of the colours not appearing in the series of throws?

3 - red
1 - yellow
4 - green

I'm stuck with figuring out the complement properly - it is P("All the colours appear during three throws"), right? I tried to solve this drawing a 8x8 table with all the possible outcomes of all the colours appearing during the last throw - not getting it right...

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let X be the probability of all showing up out of 3 throws and Y the probability of at least one not showing up out of 3 throws. In this way you can write

$$P(Y) = 1 - P(X)$$
$$P(X) = \frac{3}{8}\frac{1}{8}\frac{4}{8}3!$$
Hence: $$P(Y) = 1 - \frac{12}{8^3}3!$$

Comment: I was going for the 3/8 x 1/8 x 4/8 (times 3), but did not realize the 3! Can't get my head around why the extra multipliers (2 and 1)... It seems I have to study combinatorics :)

Comment: Imagine if you'd have to write down all the combinations for the 3 throws that land different colors. How many combinations are there ?